# How to update state for device width using Hooks in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, according to my scenario, a have button in my project and I have written two functions to change background color. First function will call if device width is less than or equal to 320px. Second function will call if device width is === 768px. but here the problem is when my device width is 320px when I click the button at that time the background color is changing to red here the problem comes now when I go to 768px screen then initially my button background color has to be in blue color, but it is showing red. to show button background color blue I have to update state for device size.

So someone please help me to achieve this.

This is my code

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [backGroundColor, setBackGroundColor] = useState(null)

  const [deviceSize, changeDeviceSize] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  const changeBackGroundColorForMobile = () => {
    if(deviceSize <= 320) {
      setBackGroundColor({
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      })
    }
  }

  const changeBackGroundColorForTab = () => {
    if(deviceSize === 768) {
      setBackGroundColor({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      })
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
            <button onClick={() => {changeBackGroundColorForMobile(); changeBackGroundColorForTab() }} style={backGroundColor} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

If you have any questions please let me know thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- You're always running two functions. Don’t need that.
- You’re updating the `deviceSize` only on the initial render. You have to update that in orientation change also.
- Set the default colour always to *blue*.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [backGroundColor, setBackGroundColor] = useState({
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }); // Initialize bgColor with "blue"

  const [deviceSize, changeDeviceSize] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeW = () => changeDeviceSize(window.innerWidth);

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeW); // Update the width on resize

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeW);
  });

  const changeBgColor = () => {
    let bgColor = "blue";
    if (deviceSize === 768) {
      bgColor = "green";
    } else if (deviceSize <= 320) {
      bgColor = "red";
    }

    setBackGroundColor({
      backgroundColor: bgColor
    });
  }; // Update the bgColor by considering the deviceSize

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <div className="first">
            <button
              onClick={changeBgColor}
              style={backGroundColor}
              className="btn btn-primary"
            >
              Click here
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi @Yushan I tried your code it's not updating the width.

Comment: @Vimsi, I have updated the resize code. Now check.

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the previous advice to get the width and if you have lots of child components that rely on the width then I would suggest using the useContext hook so you don't have to keep passing the window data as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`useWindowSize()`](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize) hook to get window width. And whenever width changes you can change background color by calling the functions in `useEffect()`

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Usage
function App() {
   const [backGroundColor, setBackGroundColor] = useState(null)

  const { width } = useWindowSize();

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(width <= 320) {
      changeBackGroundColorForMobile();
    }
    if(width === 768) {
      changeBackGroundColorForTab()
    }
  }, [width])

  const changeBackGroundColorForMobile = () => {

      setBackGroundColor({
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      })
    
  }

  const changeBackGroundColorForTab = () => {

      setBackGroundColor({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      })
    
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <div className='first'>
            <button style={backGroundColor} className='btn btn-primary'>Click here</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

// Hook
function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
  // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }

    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();

    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount

  return windowSize;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shreyas Jadhav I tried your code it is saying size is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` hook to add an event listener to window resize.

```
export default function App() {
  const [bgClassName, setBgClassName] = useState("btn-primary");
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    function updateWidth() {
      setWidth(window.innerWidth);

      if(window.innerWidth === 768){
        setBgClassName('btn-primary')
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidth);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWidth);
  }, []);

  const changeColor = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 320) {
      setBgClassName("btn-danger");
    } else if (window.innerWidth === 768) {
      setBgClassName("btn-success");
    }
  };

  console.log(width);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12">
          <div className="first">
            <button
              onClick={() => changeColor()}
              className={`btn ${bgClassName}`}
            >
              Click here
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```